# ng-route is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am posting my code can you please whats wrong in the code.
when i click on anchor tag "contacts" it will not change the view...
 i already define the to separate controllers.

Thanks In advance......):

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-route.js"> </script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/app.js">enter code here</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<h1>Welcome to ITYX</h1>
    <p><a href="#main">Home</a></p>
    <p><a href="#contact">Contact</a></p>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app =angular.module("myModule",['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/',{
            templateUrl:'templates/main.html',
            controller:'mainController'
    }).
    when('/contact',{
        templateUrl:'templates/contact.html',
         controller:'contactController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
}]);
app.controller('mainController',function($scope){
    $scope.message ="hi am in main section";
});
    app.controller('contactController',function($scope){
        console.log("contact controller");
    $scope.message ="hi am in contact section";
});
```

**main.html**

```
<h1>Main Section</h1>
{{message}}
```

**contact.html**

```
<h1>Contact Section</h1>
{{message}}
```

Comment: Have you tried `a href="#/contact">Contact</a>`?

Comment: did you get any error on console?

Comment: For me this used to work: `<a href="/#/contact">Contact</a>`

Comment: hey mark as answer so it will be useful for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have it as,

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1>Welcome to ITYX</h1>
        <div class="nav">
          <a href="#main" class="button">Main</a>
          <a href="#contact" class="button">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6eSUYcaFEzAZkExKN5KR?p=preview)**

Comment: why did you remove the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It must be your paths to either your files or angular. I've made a plunker to verify that your code works if you reference files correctly.

 
[Plunker implementation of your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/UZSvVyxsP0N11HRnFTuH?p=preview)

With the only different to be:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool have a great day!